# overriding Devises "You are already signed in" by signing the user out, redirecting to authentication page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I change from showing this message to logging the user out and redirecting him to an authentication page? From other threads on the subject, I understood that the Devise SessionsController has to be altered, but I don't understand how to apply those examples to mine and where is this controller even located?

I'm working on an app where I have a `User` model and a `Page` model, like on Facebook. Both of these models have Devise added to them. When I'm signed in under a User account and try to create the page, I get the "You are already signed in" message and the log shows `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected`. When a signed in user tries to create a page, what I want to happen is to get redirected to the page, where this user can either log back in and by doing so confirm that he wants this page under his account, or create a whole new account under different email that will only manage this new page.

create method for pages

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.'
 }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

page model

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, :through => :likes
  has_many :events
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :likes
  has_many :pages, :through => :likes
end
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam , what do you need to see, though? form for new page, user model, page model...?

Comment: yeah, the models and the corresponding controller.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam updated